# Django - get data from form and return to user so they can edit/delete

Tags: python, django, database, form-data, django-class-based-views

New to Django and making a restuarant booking system. I have everything going to my database but now i'm trying to return the info back to the user, ideally in a similar form view to what i have, so they can edit or delete the booking.

My code so far is as follows:

models.py:

```
class Reservations(models.Model):

    reservation form categories and attributes
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phoneNumberRegex], max_length=16, 
unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.CharField(choices=time_options, default="12pm", max_length=10)
    number_of_party = models.IntegerField(choices=party_size, default=1)
    reservation_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, 
editable=False, max_length=15)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date']
        verbose_name = 'Reservation'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reservations'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then my form looks like this:

form.py:

```
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservations
        fields = ['name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'date', 'time', 'number_of_party']
        widgets = {
            'date': DatePickerInput(format='%d-%m-%Y'),
        }
```

Then where I think i'm really getting lost is with the views.

view.py:

```
class ReservationsFormView(CreateView):
    model = Reservations
    template_name = "reservations/reservations.html"
    form_class = ReservationForm
    success_url = "reservation_complete/"



    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)


class EditReservationView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Reservations
    template_name = "reservations/edit_reservations.html"
    form_class = ReservationForm
    success_url = "reservation_complete/"

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == self.get_object().user


class ReservationCompleteView(CreateView):
    template_name = "reservations/reservation_complete.html"
    success_url = "/reservation_complete/"
    form_class = ReservationForm
    model = Reservations


class ReservationAccountView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "reservations/reservations_account.html"

class DeleteReservationView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    """ A view to delete an reservation """
    model = Reservations
    success_url = "/reservations/"

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == self.get_object().user
```

So basically if someone could help me extract the data and present back to the user in a html file I would greatly appreciate it.
A lot of the material online isn't using class based views but i start that way so sticking it out.
Sorry for the verbose code.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

While Django's Edit, Create, etc views are quick and helpful, I find them hard to manipulate, especially if I haven't used them in a while. I recommend getting used to writing your own views, that way you can set whatever action you want the view to perform.

Let's say your URL looks like this - `edit/4281ee81-a12a-4a0f-8928-2d9639903bd7/`

`forms.py`

```
class EditReservationForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

`views.py`

```
class EditReservationView(LoginRequiredMixing, View):
    def get(self, request, *args **kwargs):
        reservation = Reservations.objects.get(uuid=kwargs['uuid'])
        form = EditReservationForm(initial={"name": reservation.name, "email": reservation.email})
        return render(request, "reservation/edit-reservation.html", {"form": form})
```

You now have a bound form to data from a specific reservation. I hope this helps. And more info on initial data here - [initial form values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values)

Comment: Thanks man. Will try it out this way and see